# Shared colorbar for one row of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.9)
cax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.075, 0.8])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The above code provides a shared colorbar for all 4 plots.  How can I best amend this if I only wanted the colorbar to apply to the subplots in the top row?  I would like the colorbar to only take up space in the top row of the subplots; the second row of subplots would then take up the space vacated by the smaller colorbar.

I hope this makes sense, many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html Does a column sharing a colorbar.  It works the same way for a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you can use the new `subfigures` functionality if you really want the two rows to have different width axes:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
sfig0, sfig1 = fig.subfigures(2, 1)

axs = sfig0.subplots(1, 2)
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
for ax in axs.flat:
    pc = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((100, 100)), 
                       cmap=cmap)
sfig0.colorbar(pc, ax=axs)

axs = sfig1.subplots(1, 2)
cmap = plt.cm.BuPu_r
for ax in axs.flat:
    pc = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((100, 100)), 
                       cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much!

Comment: subfigures are pretty new so google searches are going to have trouble turning this up.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easy way to do it.  Note `ax` is the kwarg, not `cax`, for this to work.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=True)
pc = [None] * 4
for nn, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    if nn > 1:
        cmap = plt.cm.BuPu_r
    else:
        cmap = plt.cm.viridis
    pc[nn] = ax.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), 
                       cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(pc[0], ax=axs[0, :])
fig.colorbar(pc[2], ax=axs[1, :])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Conversely, you cannot get what you want where the second row fills out the space vacated by the colorbar.

Answer (score 0):

#### Changing size and position of colorbar with matplotlib

[mpl.pyplot.colorbar(mappable=None, cax=None, ax=None, **kw)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-colorbar) places the colorbar on an axis made specifically for it (cax) or an axis with room to place the colorbar (ax). [mpl.axes(arg)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html) makes a new axis at a 4 tuple location. The 4 tuple indicates distance from bottom, distance from left, bar width, and bar height  (bottom, left, width, height).

```
cax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.075, 0.8])
```

You can solve your problem by simply making the axis you place the colorbar shorter and positioned higher from the bottom.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.9)
cax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.575, 0.035, 0.3])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax)
```